# Disable new account email notification in WooCommerce based on current product type in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, email-notifications

For a client that uses learndash, i stumbled upon a quite unhandy feature. This elearning integration requires that clients are forced to create an account in the checkout and receive an email about it. For a sold course this is good, however, this client wants to sell other things as well.

So as this plugin does not function without the forced account creation, i wanted to remove the new account email to customers when the purchased product types are not 'course'.

So far i have:

```php
function disable_account_creation_email( $email_class ) {
    $order = wc_get_order();
    $product_type = '';
    if (!empty($order)){
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item){
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $product_type   .= $product->get_type();
        }
        if (stripos($product_type,'course') ===false){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer_notification', array( $email_class, 'customer_new_account' ), 10, 3 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'disable_account_creation_email' );
```

However, it doesnt work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple mistakes in your current code

You can use the `woocommerce_email_enabled_customer_new_account` filter hook.

- Checks for checkout/cart page
- This answer checks whether a product is of type `simple` **- Replace with your own product type**
- Tested in WooCommerce 5.0.0 and it works, explanation via commenttags added to the code

---

1. Use this to check when **1** of the products in cart is of a certain type

```php
function filter_woocommerce_email_enabled_customer_new_account( $enabled, $user, $email ) { 
    // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
    if ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            // Get product
            $product = $cart_item['data'];
                    
            // Get product type
            $product_type = $product->get_type();
                    
            // Compare
            if ( $product_type == 'simple' ) {
                // Enabled = false, break loop
                $enabled = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_enabled_customer_new_account', 'filter_woocommerce_email_enabled_customer_new_account' , 10, 3 );
```

---

2. Or use the following if **ALL** products in cart should be of a certain type

```php
function filter_woocommerce_email_enabled_customer_new_account( $enabled, $user, $email ) { 
    // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
    if ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
        // Set flag
        $flag = true;
                
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            // Get product
            $product = $cart_item['data'];
                    
            // Get product type
            $product_type = $product->get_type();
                    
            // Compare
            if ( $product_type != 'simple' ) {
                $flag = false;
            }
        }
                
        // If flag is true
        if ( $flag ) {
            // Enabled = false
            $enabled = false;   
        }
    }
    
    return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_enabled_customer_new_account', 'filter_woocommerce_email_enabled_customer_new_account' , 10, 3 );
```